# jQuery plugin for drawing scene with simple shapes, supporting drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draw

I'm looking for some jQuery plugin which would help me to achieve following goals:

1. Present user with some fixed size canvas which will be used for arranging "scene"
2. Allow for putting basic shapes, custom objects onto the scene
3. Support drag-and-drop for elements in scene
4. Support "snip to grid"

Any ideas?

Comment: try [easelJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/dragdrop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/), it provides lot of ui elements with great functionality like drag, drop etc and comes with browser compatibility for free.

To get grid snap like features, use following settings:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        grid: [10, 20],
        drag: function() {
            // custom code
        }
    });
```

});

There are also more nice settings, like snap to other elements, etc. See full documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-drag)

Answer (score 0):

jquery UI is not the library I was looking for, since it only provides support for Drag'n'Drop, nothing more from my list. One particular interesting library I found is http://raphaeljs.com/. You can easily build a canvas on which user can draw custom shapes, it has a lot of built in tools which can reduce boilerplate code and it also supports D'n
'D. I think Snap to Grid will gave to be performed manually, but I find this library to be quite nice and powerful.

I'll wait for other replies, maybe someone knows of something better.

**Edit**
It appears that raphaeljs doesn't handle dragging and dropping images out of the box (some custom code required). I went with jQuery UI again and decided that it's far more better.